# Merge n number of adjacent polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, polygon, merge, grouping

I have over 17,000 individual polygons. I want to merge two adjacent polygons so that I finish with approximately 8,500 polygons. The polygons need to be merged based on location, merge two adjacent polygons. Then merge the next two adjacent polygons and so on. Is there a way to do this through ArcGIS or Python?

[image: Screen grab example]

[image]

This is a sample of the python code I am trying to use

```python
#Import arcpy
import arcpy,os,datetime,re
import math
from arcpy import env


#The filepath location
mxdPathA3P="C:\\Users\\heff\\Desktop\\ArcGIS_data\\HSCU_Mapping\\HSCU_A3_Portrait_Template.mxd"

#Set the workspace environment
arcpy.env.workspace = 'C:\\Users\\heffernanv\\Desktop\\ArcGIS_data\\ARCPY_WORK'


inpgs=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mapdoc,u'POLYGON_LAYER',mainDF)[0]


# tempMerged = temporary merged polygon shapefile (better to have this in-memory)
where1 = '"' + 'Shape_Area' + '" < 125000000.0000'
shapeField = arcpy.Describe(inpgs).ShapeFieldName

#Read polygon geometry into dictionary; key = GridID, value = geometry
geometryDictionary = {}
polyrows = arcpy.SearchCursor(inpgs)
for prow in polyrows:
    geometryDictionary[prow.GridID] = prow.shapeField
del prow
del polyrows

#Loop through catchments that are to be dissolved
polyrows = arcpy.SearchCursor(inpgs, where1)
for prow in polyrows:

    #Get geometries of two polygons
    # grd1 = GridID on the current polygon
    # grd2 = GridID on the polygon downstream
    geometry1 = prow.shapeField
    geometry2 = geometryDictionary[grd2]

    #Merge datasets
    arcpy.Merge_management([geometry1, geometry2], tempMerged)

    #Dissolve
    arcpy.Dissolve_management(tempMerged, outpgs)
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot and a more detailed explaination please?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour]. There is an [edit] button beneath your question that you can use to revise it with more details.  What's missing is any sort of explanation of how you would decide which pairs of adjacent polygons would get merged (dissolved?) and which would not.

Comment: I have polygons of individual areas, however I want to expand the size of the polygons. To do this I need to merge each of the polygons with it's adjacent polygon.

Comment: I just need to merge the two adjacent polygons, the size of the polygons don't matter. The polygons don't share attributes to merge them.

Comment: I hope the extra information I added, helps

Comment: How should this tool notice that you do not want to unify the polygon from the upper left corner and the one right from it instead the one beyond? Is there any attributive grouping taking place?

Comment: I could work from lower left corner and continue, it doesn't matter. There is no attribute grouping. Each polygon has an individual block number

Comment: By ruling out Python use you've made the task more difficult (by at least an order of magnitude).  The only way to select neighboring features and alter an attribute so they can be merged would be to manually edit the feature class. It takes a lot less to learn Python than the weeks ahead without it.

Comment: ok I have a basic understanding of python. Could you suggest how it would be completed using python?

Comment: Without the other requests for clarification resolved (explicitly stating your goals and criteria in the problem statement), I doubt anyone would be able to suggest a solution.

Comment: I have added a sample python code of how I am trying to merge the polygons

Comment: So you always want to group exactly two neighbourghs, no matter how exactly they touch each other (meaning one laying north and one south, or one in the west and one east)? What happens if there are no adjacent polygons for a given one which have not alray been handled?

Comment: Correct, I want to join it no matter what. That is a good point, I assumed they would all adjoin to one adjacent polygon, I guess if there are no adjacent polygons which have not already been handled, the polygon should remain as it is. No join to occur

Comment: Can you replace your picture with a much simpler one, please?  I think it should just include enough polygons (perhaps a dozen) to illustrate the edge cases like three or more contiguous polygons, and discontiguous groups of polygons, if they occur.

Comment: I have replaced the picture with some contiguous polygons and some edge polygons. All polygons are all adjacent to at least one other polygon

Comment: To me, what you are asking is still unclear.  Picture a fishnet grid of 2x2 = 4 polygons.  How should these be merged?  I think you need to illustrate the algorithm you wish to use.

Comment: It doesn't matter how they are merged. They can be merged from left to right and if there is none to the right merge with the adjacent polygon above or below. The main aim is to reduce the number of polygons by half and subsequently increase the size of each polygon area.